# How to prevent outgoing voip fax calls?

Tags: asterisk, voip, fax

Is it possible to make a condition of outgoing VoIP calls on Asterisk?

```
if(the receiver is a fax){
  don't start calling;
}
```

If not, can we log(save) outgoing fax calls(with call info like time, duration, channel, location) into a file somehow?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to detect when a fax machine answeres an outgoing call. NV_FaxDetect in calls. For more details use this link.

[Using Asterisk to Detect and Redirect Fax Calls](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff755051(v=ocs.14).aspx)

Comment: This one availible only for very old asterisk. For new asterisk faxdetect availible only for dahdi channels and t.38 sip re-invites.